# How can I create a travis script for Haskel/stack?

Tags: haskell, continuous-integration, travis-ci, dependency-management, haskell-stack

I've seen quite a few travis stack scripts, they seemed pretty complicated, I don't think they have to be so complicated.

Here's mine:

```
language: haskell
sudo: false

ghc:
- '7.10.3'
```

Locally I compile my app by "stack build".

How can I add "stack" to the travis file properly? At the moment I need only stack, no tests.

Comment: Travis' [Haskell VM images](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Haskell-VM-images) don't have much that would be useful for a modern Haskell project. You should go with Michael Snoyman's advice or simply copy from other projects.

Answer (score 3):

There's a very thorough example at

http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#travis-with-caching

It used to be much smaller, but we added support to that to build with both Stack and cabal, which complicated things a lot. You can always trim it down to remove support for some of the more complicated features.

Comment: it's too much complicated, it's unclear what to remove from it and what keep. why is the language "c", not haskell?

Comment: The reason is documented in the file: it's lighter weight, and we're providing our own build tools

Comment: "It used to be much smaller, but but we added support to that to build with both Stack and cabal, which complicated things a lot."  I have a project that copied one of those older, smaller `.travis.yml` files, so I'll just [link to it](https://github.com/sacundim/tau-sigma/blob/master/.travis.yml) for reference.